# trigger filldown formula based on cell of another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, eventtrigger

I have four worksheets and I write one formula in cell F2 which trigger a filldown for all the rest. I already have the trigger private sub to call my procedure that works. Is there a way to make this sub more efficient?

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillDownFormula_test2()
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 ' Filldown a formula for in column of data.
 ' Assumes a data table with headings in the first row,
 ' the formula in the second row and is the active cell.
 ' this one is tested based on set range
 ' Test results were positive
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
 Dim rngData As Range
 Dim rngFormula As Range, rng2Formula As Range
 Dim rowData As Long
 Dim colData As Long
 Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

 Set ws = wb.Sheets("Feuil1")


 With ws

' Set the ranges
 Set rng = wb.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("F2")
 Set rngData = rng.CurrentRegion

' Set the row and column variables
 rowData = rngData.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 colData = rng.Column

' Set the formula range and fill down the formula
 Set rngFormula = rngData.Offset(1, colData - 1).Resize(rowData - 1, 1)
 rngFormula.FillDown

 'G2 is a different formulas but same on every sheets
 Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("G2")


' Set the row and column variables
 rowData = rngData.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 colData = rng2.Column

' Set the formula range and fill down the formula
 Set rng2Formula = rngData.Offset(1, colData - 1).Resize(rowData - 1, 1)
 rng2Formula.FillDown
 End With



 With ws2
Set rng = wb.Sheets("Feuil2").Range("F2")
 Set rngData = rng.CurrentRegion

' Set the row and column variables
    rowData = rngData.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
   colData = rng.Column

' Set the formula range and fill down the formula
 Set rngFormula = rngData.Offset(1, colData - 1).Resize(rowData - 1, 1)
 rngFormula.FillDown

 Set rng2 = wb.Sheets("Feuil2").Range("G2")


' Set the row and column variables
 rowData = rngData.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
 colData = rng2.Column

' Set the formula range and fill down the formula
 Set rng2Formula = rngData.Offset(1, colData - 1).Resize(rowData - 1, 1)
     rng2Formula.FillDown



 End With
 End Sub
```

One last question: what would've been the most efficient to do one range at the time so it allows me to enter formula before doing the second one. ( I have six formulas to filldown)

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look something like this...

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillDownFormula_test2()
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 ' Filldown a formula for in column of data.
 ' Assumes a data table with headings in the first row,
 ' the formula in the second row and is the active cell.
 ' this one is tested based on set range
 ' Test results were positive
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Feuil1")

    With ws
        Call FillDownData(.Range("F2"), Range("F2").CurrentRegion)
        Call FillDownData(.Range("G2"), Range("G2").CurrentRegion)
    End With

    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Feuil2")

    With ws2
        Call FillDownData(.Range("F2"), Range("F2").CurrentRegion)
        Call FillDownData(.Range("G2"), Range("G2").CurrentRegion)
    End With

End Sub

Function FillDownData(rng As Range, rngData As Range)

    Dim rowData As Long
    Dim colData As Long
    Dim rngFormula As Range

' Set the row and column variables
    rowData = rngData.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    colData = rng.column
Debug.Print rowData & " " & colData
' Set the formula range and fill down the formula
    'Set rngFormula = rngData.Offset(1, colData - 1).Resize(rowData - 1, 1)
    'rngFormula.FillDown

End Function
```

Comment: I tried it but it looks like a unfinished loop on bigger list

Comment: I don't see a loop in here at all, I'm not sure what you mean... Also, try using  the `Debug.Printer` somewhere to debug where it's stopping

Comment: Debug is going to help why it keeps running? ok I'm going to try it. I don't know it works alone but with the event trigger it never stop. Anyways I'll get back to you

Comment: Do you mean that the data is just not stop filling to the end of the spread sheet?

Comment: Yes that is what happening

Comment: Use `Debug.Print colData & " " & rowData` and see what that's out putting, you may want to comment out the last two lines as well since that's what is creating the "infinite loop". I've updated my answer to reflect